# Can I use sticky horizontal scrollbar in ANT design table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have read ANT document about table and they described sticky but can't find how to use. I tried the below and nothing changed.

```
<Table  
bordered 
columns={columns} 
columns={mergedColumns} 
dataSource={data} 
scroll={{x: 700}} 
sticky="true" 
size="small" />
```

Comment: Which version of AntD are you using? It's only supported in 4.6.0 and onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You assign the string `"true"` to a boolean property. Either use the verbose

```js
sticky={true}
```

or the compact form

```
sticky
```